# Inlining logo with header element

Tags: html, css

HTML Code:

```
<div class="header">

   <img src=".jpg" width="240" height="180" >

    <h1>MY APPS</h1>
    <p>TRY AND ERROR, CODING IS FUN</p>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0.7);
  }

 .header img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
}


 .header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 18px;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 12.5px
 }

 .header p {
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 12.5px
 }
```

How can I put `<img>` inline with my `<h1>` ?

Comment: add a div around the img and h1 and set display:flex or set display:inline to img and h1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that very easily using `flexbox`:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 }

header img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img>
  <div>
    <h1>MY APPS</h1>
    <p>TRY AND ERROR, CODING IS FUN</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

You can read more about `flexbox` here: https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/

Also, you could replace `<div class="header">` with a `<header>` element here to make your HTML more semantic. I did that in the example already.

Comment: Thankyou, but i want to move all my header elements to the center.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with coding and don't forget to look into the article. If you are creating a custom layout, the `flexbox` will be of much help many times in the future ;-)

Comment: Duly noted. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad I helped. You could help my answer too - with an upvote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
.header{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  }

 .header img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-content h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.header-content p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

   <img src=".jpg" width="240" height="180" >
   <div class="header-content">
      <h1>MY APPS</h1>
    <p>TRY AND ERROR, CODING IS FUN</p>    
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but do you know how to move the logo in the center also?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with display property:

```css
   

.header {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.header img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.header-text{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-left:10px;
}

.header h1 {
  margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

.header p {
 margin:0
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src=".jpg" width="240" height="180">
  <div class="header-text">
    <h1>MY APPS</h1>
    <p>TRY AND ERROR, CODING IS FUN</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou, but i want to move all my header elements to the center.